# What is the correct Select Statement for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

//This is my Table 1

```
    TransactionNum     Type  
    65658               0  
    65659               0  
    65660              449  
    65661               0
```

//This is My Table 2

```
    Type    Description          
    445 Discount #1  
    446 Discount #2  
    447 Discount #3  
    448 Discount #4  
    449 Discount #5  
    450 Discount #6
```

//This is My Script

```
    SELECT a.TransactionNum,b.Description FROM Table1 a,Table2 b
    WHERE a.Type=b.Type ORDER BY TransactionNum
```

//Result

```
    TransactionNum   Description
    65659            Discount #4
```

//I want the result to be like this, The TransactionNum with 0 type should also be included in the result, Please help me with this, Im using SQL2000 here.

```
    TransactionNum      Description   
    65658               0  
    65659               0  
    65660              Discount #5  
    65661               0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead,

```
SELECT a.TransactionNum, 
       COALESCE(b.Description, CAST (a.Type AS VARCHAR(20))) AS Description
FROM   Table1 a LEFT JOIN Table2 b
          ON a.Type=b.Type
ORDER  BY a.TransactionNum
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/003f8/4)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ TRANSACTIONNUM ║ DESCRIPTION ║
╠════════════════╬═════════════╣
║          65658 ║ 0           ║
║          65659 ║ 0           ║
║          65660 ║ Discount #5 ║
║          65661 ║ 0           ║
╚════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: He is using SQL SERVER 2000 not MySQL

Comment: @hvd - Not talking about Left join. `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Discount #5' to data type int`

Comment: @hims056 To be fair, the OP didn't specify the type of `Type`, it *could* be a `varchar` column :) But yeah, you are probably right that `a.Type` needs to be cast.

Comment: @hims056 good point. The reason why I didn't cast it to varchar is because the OP didn't tell about the datatype of cast. Just by loookign at the record we can't 100% tell what the datatype is `:D` anyway you're right.

Comment: @JW - Now it's a perfect answer. :) just updated the SQLFiddle for SQL Server.

Comment: @hims056, Thanks for this It got a correct result, but when I add this another condition (ON a.Type=b.Type WHERE a.Trandate=20130401), I still got the same result, I forgot to say,There is another column here "TransactionDate", What is the correct script?

Comment: @odlanyer - Can you update your question with exact Columns and types?

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle we can use left outer join

```
     SELECT a.TransactionNum,b.Description FROM Table1 a,Table2 b
     WHERE a.Type=b.Type(+) ORDER BY TransactionNum
```

Comment: Why would you recommend that style of join? [Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm): "Oracle recommends that you use the `FROM` clause `OUTER JOIN` syntax rather than the Oracle join operator."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  **To write a query that performs an outer join of tables A and B and returns all rows from B (a right outer join), use the RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN syntax in the FROM clause, or apply the outer join operator (+) to all columns of A in the join condition in the WHERE clause. For all rows in B that have no matching rows in A, Oracle returns null for any select list expressions containing columns of A.** <br>  Oracle provides both options . If my understanding is wrong please correct me.

Comment: Oracle does, currently, support both options. But as I linked to, they *recommend* that you use the `OUTER JOIN` syntax. Since the `OUTER JOIN` syntax is also the ANSI standard syntax, and will work across all compliant database systems, why would you recommend an Oracle-only syntax?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Thank you for the clarification , point noted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.TransactionNum,isnull(b.Description,0)
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
On a.Type = b.Type
Order by a.TransactionNum
```